# Azure Storage CRUD operations using .NET Core

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been working with Azure Storage resources recently, particularly I was just playing around with CRUD operations in Table. I was able to accomplish a task using .NET Framework, however, recently my requirements have changed and I had to migrate to .NET Core. I wrote the same type of code by it reaches `try-catch` statement in `CreateTable()` and stop for no reason, I am not getting any exceptions or messages, program just exits from there. I have been trying to figure out this issue, so far I came to the following solution that seems to be missing a tiny piece to make it work.

Moreover, previously I was using CosmosDB API to perform this operations. Unfortunately, it is not available in .NET Core, therefore I came up with this solution.

My thoughts: I am concerned about authentication part as well, since I can't determine if it was successful or not. It goes through `Auth()` well without problems. I would appreciate if anyone could give me the right direction to the solution of this problem. Thanks!

```
    static CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Auth();
        CreateTable();
    }
    static void Auth()
    {
         _storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
             new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
                 "MyResource", "MyKey"),true);
    }

    async static void CreateTable()
    {
        CloudTableClient tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable peopleTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("XYZ");
        try
        {
            await peopleTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        People customer = new People("Garry", "Johnson");
        customer.Email = "xxx@yyy.zzz";
        customer.PhoneNumber = "123456789";
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer);
        var result = await peopleTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be awaiting the call to `CreateTable` method in your Main method as this is an async method?

Comment: @GauravMantri good catch, but it isn’t a point

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “it isn’t a point”.

Comment: @GauravMantri I mean that it was a nice call, but it doesn’t anyhow help to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks but now I’m confused:). You mentioned that your code/program is exiting. That was because you were not waiting for the asynchronous operation to finish. Have you tried Tom’s solution below? Are you still having the same problem?

Comment: @GauravMantri it exits reaching `try-catch`. I am about to try Tom's solution right now.

Comment: Yeah @GauravMantri is explaining the same. `async void` wont wait for the async task to be executed. Tom sun is explaining exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote the same type of code by it reaches try-catch statement in CreateTable() and stop for no reason.

As the CreateTable() is an async method, the program will exit with no wait to get exectution result.

> I would appreciate if anyone could give me the right direction to the solution of this problem

Please have a try to use the following demo code. If get the 204 in the console meanings that create table and insert record to the table successfully, or you will get the exception information in the console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Auth();
            var result = CreateTable().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

async static Task<string> CreateTable()
{
      CloudTableClient tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
      CloudTable peopleTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("XYZ");
      try
         {
                await peopleTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                People customer = new People("Garry", "Johnson");
                customer.Email = "xxx@yyy.zzz";
                customer.PhoneNumber = "123456789";
                TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer);
                var result = await peopleTable.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
                return result.HttpStatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;

  }
```